# Isolate power supply with a HX1188NL

Tags: power-supply, isolation

I need to isolate a 24V DC power supply using the [HX1188NL](https://www.farnell.com/cad/2615863.pdf) component.

How can I connect the ground to the two sides of the transformer? Do I have to short the centre sockets with the negative pin?

[image]

Comment: That's an isolation transformer for Ethernet signals, not an isolation transformer for a power supply.  It doesn't have a rating for power handling.  It is intended for frequencies well above power line frequencies.

Comment: @JRE Thank you for your reply. I also saw that it is mainly used for Ethernet signals, but other datasheets of the component like [this](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2699975.pdf) (at page 5 of the pdf) report possible applications in other areas as well. Regardless of the use, I would be curious to know please how the connections could be made in case a supply voltage is used.

Comment: Assuming AC, then just ignore the center tap.

Comment: @JRE Thanks, and with a DC supply?

Comment: DC doesn't pass through transformers.

Comment: The other uses on that catalog page refer to communications between various components.  The transformer you are looking at would be used to isolate the various components but still allow communications between them.